# Using control character (\x1f) with string and/or StringBuilder

Tags: c#, console-application

I just want to use the ASCII Unit Separator character (decimal 31 and hex 1F) instead of a tab for a delimited file. I assume the problem is encoding but I sure can't find how to change it. In the following, I get the desired output on the console in the first line of output in my StreamWriter file but the second line is missing the '\x1f'.

```
static StreamWriter sw = null;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        sw = new StreamWriter(OutFilename, false, Encoding.UTF8);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File open error: " + ex.Message);
        return;
    }
    // This works
    Output("From▼To");  // Has a '\x1f' in it
    // This does not work
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("From");
    sb.Append('\x1f');
    sb.Append("To");
    Output(sb.ToString());
    //
    sw.Close();
}

static void Output(string s)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
    sw.WriteLine(s);
}
```

The output file has:

```
From▼To
FromTo
```

I want to build a string using StringBuilder except with the '\x1f' in the output.

Comment: Are you sure `▼` is `\x1F`? because I get `\x25BC` for that character when I check the array returned from `"From▼To".ToCharArray()`

Comment: Try `\u001f` and let me know if that works.

Comment: either x1F or u001F will not work, as these are not printable characters. You need to find another character than you can use to represent that arrow

Comment: That char '▼' is decimal 9660 or hexadecimal 25BC, to use as '\u25BC'

Comment: @Blas Soriano, I do not need to print the characters. I chose the one character that is explicitly provided for doing exactly what I am doing. The advantage is that I can be sure it will never be in text to be printed. The fact that the character does show in the first line indicates the problem is not that it is not being printed.

Comment: I'm not sure if that would be ok for you, but if you inspect the sringbuilder, you will see you are using `\u25BC` even if you pasted the char as an ascii 31. Check [this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/zpE0mio.png)

Comment: Your having typed Alt+31 does not mean you have entered the character whose code point is 31. It means you have entered character whose *glyph* is the same as the glyph numbered 31 in the OEM code page of your Windows system (and all code pages used for OEM use the down arrow glyph in position 31, so you've entered the character U+25BC). To actually enter character with code point 31 you have to type Alt+*0*31.

Comment: Okay, Andrey, well at least what you say seems relevant. I opened the text file using the VS binary editor and now I see I was wrong. I apologize to everyone, it is not x1f. When I use the VS binary editor I can see that the escape character is working. I should have used the VS binary editor sooner.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is a lot of confusion here.  Let me see if I can clear things up somewhat.

First of all, let's agree on the following points that are easily verifiable:

```
'\x1f' == '\u001F'
'\x1f' == (char)31
'\x1f' != '▼' // <-- here appears to be your mistaken assumption.
'▼' == (char)9660
'▼' == '\u25BC'
```

So this...

```
// This works
Output("From▼To");  // Has a '\x1f' in it
```

... ironically is the exact line that does not work.  There is no `'\x1f'` in this string.  The triangle character is not `'\x1f'`.  Not sure where you got that impression.

Which leads us to the last point: `'\x1f'` is not a visible character.  So when you try to display it in the console, you will not see it, and that is 100% normal.

However, be assured that when you have a string with `'\x1f'` and write that out to a file, the character is still there.  But you will never be able to "see" it, unless you read the bytes directly.

So whether or not you can use `'\x1f'` as a delimiter depends on whether you need the delimiter to be visible.  If yes, then you need to pick another character.  But if you only need it as a delimiter for when you programmatically parse the file, then using `'\x1f'` is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want to try your luck with such trick, you could write exactly the bytes you expect in the following way:

```
Output(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString()));
```

if you have another `Output` method like this:

```
static void Output(string s)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
    sw.WriteLine(s);
}

static void Output(byte[] bytes)
{
    int dataLength = bytes.Length;
    List<byte> modified = new List<byte>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dataLength; i++)
    {
        if (bytes[i] == 0xBC && (i < dataLength - 1) && bytes[i + 1] == 0x25)
        {
            modified.Add(0x1F);
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            modified.Add(bytes[i]);
        }
    }
    byte[] data = modified.ToArray();
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes));      // Use this or the next line
    // Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
    sw.BaseStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    sw.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: ASCII(31) is named "US" (Unit Separator), when handled as a control character. I don't know what the effect would be by using it inside a UTF8 encoded text, but I assume you avoid using ASCII from your code `sw = new StreamWriter(OutFilename, false, Encoding.UTF8);`